# R index xyz array where xy identical for all z

Tags: r, arrays, indexing

I have array of logical matrices (CT scan mask) and want to find which xy are true for all z (axial) as a matrix.

```
tst_logi_lst <- list(matrix(as.logical(c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)),3,3),
 matrix(as.logical(c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1)),3,3), matrix(as.logical(c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)),3,3))

tst_logi_arr <- array(data=unlist(tst_logi_lst), c(3,3,3))

tst_logi_arr
, , 1

      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE

, , 2

      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE

, , 3

      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

The desired result is :

```
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

using `apply` in the following notation just gives a calculated copy

```
tst_logi_all_t <- apply(tst_logi_arr,c(1:2,3), isTRUE)
```

And I can't summon the proper `sapply` approach that my above return matrix requires.

Based on the great answers below and considering multiple processing of `(512,512,232)`, which to use? Timings:

```
res <- 
microbenchmark(
apply(tst_logi_arr, 1:2, sum) == dim(tst_logi_arr)[3],
apply(tst_logi_arr, 1:2, all),
apply(tst_logi_arr, 1, rowSums)==dim(tst_logi_arr)[3],
times=1000L)
print(res)
Unit: microseconds                                                       expr    min       lq
   apply(tst_logi_arr, 1:2, sum) == dim(tst_logi_arr)[3] 124.54 131.2475
                           apply(tst_logi_arr, 1:2, all) 120.98 127.2290
 apply(tst_logi_arr, 1, rowSums) == dim(tst_logi_arr)[3] 172.58 178.3720
     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 156.4186 137.7265 153.3065 5415.099  1000  a 
 146.2112 133.9650 152.3310  625.676  1000  a 
 209.4132 187.2280 207.6925 5394.308  1000   b
```

`all` by a nose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `sum` (`TRUE` == 1) and look where it's `3`.

```
apply(tst_logi_arr, 1:2, sum) == dim(tst_logi_arr)[3]
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
# [1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Or shorter, as @arg0naut91 suggested:

```
apply(tst_logi_arr, 1:2, all)
```

*Note:* To get the array from your list you may alternatively  do:

```
tst_logi_arr <- simplify2array(tst_logi_lst)
```

Comment: It could be shortened to `apply(tst_logi_arr, 1:2, all)`

Answer (score 0):

An option with `colSums`

```
apply(tst_logi_arr, 1, rowSums) == 3
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
#[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: If these are `oro.nifti` objects of CT_scans where there may be a couple of hundred z , this generalizes to `rowSums) == dim(your_logi_arr@.Data)[3]`.